# I have a folder with many .tar.gz files. In python I want to go into each file unzip or compress and find text file that has string I want to extract?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, filereader, tar, gzip

I have main folder with many gz.tar compress files. So I need to unzip twice to get to a data file with text then I am extracting a certain string in the text. I am having trouble unzipping to get to the file with text then move to next file and do the same. Saving the results in a dataframe.

```
import os
import tarfile
for i in os.listdir(r'\user\project gz'):
 tar = (i, "r:gz")
 for m in tar.getmembers():
  f= tar.extractfile(member):
  if f is not None:
   content = f.read()
   text = re.findall(r"\name\s", content)
   df = pd.Dataframe(text)
   print(df)
```

Comment: try built-in module ``tarfile`` ?

Comment: @james Liu yes I imported tarfile. but still stuck

Comment: When I unzip twice 50 or so files are in each one. I need just one .txt file to run a string search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to find out file which contains the string `\name\s` in `\user\project gz\*.tar.gz`?

A solution is

```py
import os
import re
import tarfile

import pandas as pd

row = []
value = []


for filename in os.listdir(r'\\user\\project gz'):
    if filename.endswith('.tar.gz'):
        tar = tarfile.open(r'\\user\\project gz' + filename)
        for text_file in tar.getmembers():
            f = tar.extractfile(text_file)
            if f is not None:
                content = f.read().decode()
                if re.findall(r"\\name\\s", content):
                    row.append(text_file.name)
                    value.append(content)
        tar.close()


df = pd.DataFrame(value, columns=['nametag'], index=row)
print(df)
```

Comment: @steve Which specific file?

Comment: so once I got into these tar.gz files Iam looking for a text file. This text file has nametag. I trying copy the file name and name tag to a dataframe............................... file.tar -->>file.gz --->> file.txt.......... Inside this text file is a nametag. I want to copy the file name and nametag to dataframe to extract.

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codex can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: you can try f.read().decode('utf-8', errors='ignore') to ignore error

Comment: But a much better fix is to pass the correct `encoding=`. Without a way to look at the bytes in your files, we can't tell you which encoding they contain. Perhaps post a new question on [unix.se] or [su] if you can't figure it out yourself. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: Which platform you are using is not too relevant here. The content in the problematic file (ideally foucused on just a few surrounding bytes, in hex or a similarly unambiguous form) is what we are missing. The last link I provided has more information about how to present this information.